Is it possible to find out when a product category was created and/or modified and which user modified and/or created it?
I've searched on the admin backend of Magento, but obviously this information is not listed. I was wondering if it perhaps exists in the log files or whether a custom module needs to be added to track this information. Thank you for any information.

For starters, maybe this will help https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-action-log-magento-2.html
If not, you will have to install the module or write your own. by searching for "Magento 2 Admin Action Log" you will find many different ones and you can choose the one that best suits your needs
